# Minimum difference between two AP terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Given two Arithmetic Progressions, A1=ax+b and A2=cy+d, that is we're given a, b ,c & d (where a, b, c, & d all are positive integers) how have to find minimum value of |A1-A2| by choosing x and y (where x & y are also positive integers) which minimizes the absolute difference between A1 and A2.

for example -
if a=7, b=1, c=4 & d=5 then min(|A1-A2|)=0 by choosing x=4 and y=6

Comment: Eerily similar. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812575/how-to-find-the-minimum-difference-between-any-two-elements-of-two-arithmetic-se

Comment: You should read an introduction to MathJax (like [MathJax Help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) and use that to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't answer .It's Question of Running contest on Codechef
[link](https://www.codechef.com/SNCKPA16/problems/GIVCANDY)